# Tensorflow - How to reduce/broadcast a tensor with multiple workers in a cluster?

Tags: python, tensorflow, multi-gpu

I am simply trying to sum a tensor across workers in tensorflow in a synchronous way. Feels like this should be extremely easy, but I have not found a way.

I concluded that anything in tf.distribute is too abstract and I need some lower level ops, because I just want to operate on a single tensor in my program. Please correct me if there's anything in tf.distribute that just lets me reduce/broadcast a tensor that has one instance on each worker.

Here's some code where I've tried using `collective_ops.all_reduce`

```py
import sys
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.ops import collective_ops

task_id = int(sys.argv[1])
cluster = tf.train.ClusterSpec({"worker": ["localhost:2222", "localhost:2223"]})
server = tf.train.Server(cluster, job_name="worker", task_index=task_id)

with tf.device("/job:worker/task:{}/device:CPU:0".format(task_id)):
    t = tf.constant([-1,-3], name='testtensor')
    res = collective_ops.all_reduce(t, group_size=2, group_key=123, instance_key=123, merge_op='Add', final_op='Id', subdiv_offsets=(0,))

with tf.Session(server.target) as sess:

    print('running reduce..')
    print(sess.run(res))
```

If I run the above script in one terminal:
`python myscript.py 0`
and another instance in another terminal:
`python myscript.py 1`

I expect both of them to print the sum `[-2, -6]` but they are stuck in the blocking call `less.run(res)`

When I've only started one of the two processes, it keeps printing "2019-08-01 12:05:24.324155: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/master.cc:268] CreateSession still waiting for response from worker: /job:worker/replica:0/task:0",
i.e. waiting for response from the other worker.
And when I start the second process, the above logging stops, but nothing happens anyway.

I've also tried assigning a tensor to the local device using 
`with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(worker_device="/job:worker/task:0/device:CPU:0", cluster=cluster)):`
But then I just get this error trying to define the tensors:
"ValueError: Device assignment required for collective ops"

Answer (score 0):

An issue is posed on [github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31913) and receives a responding from the team member. There is a code snippet to fix this between-graph communication problem.